# How to disable the second level domain joins queries in hibernet5

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
Table Name: employee
employeeid
employeename
companyid

Table Name: company
companyid
companyname
countryid

Table Name: Country
countryid
countryname
```

I need Country Information when i query Company  so I have added EAGER for countryid in company domain

```
select 
        company0_.companyid, company0_.companyname, company0_.countryid,
        country1_.countryid, country1_.countryname
    from 
        company as company0_
        left outer join Country country1_ on (country1_.countryid =  company1_.countryid)
```

I need Company Information when i query Employee so I have added EAGER for companyid in employee domain

```
select 
        employee0_.employeeid, employee0_.employeename, employee0_.companyid,
        company1_.companyid, company1_.companyname, company1_.countryid,
        country2_.countryid, country2_.countryname
    from 
        employee as employee0_
        left outer join company company1_ on (employee0_.companyid =  company1_.companyid)
        left outer join Country country2_ on (country2_.countryid =  company1_.countryid)
```

i no need to join country information above as it is inside company doamin

When i query Employee, Company is getting joined along with it Country is also joined.

**My Requirement is**

1. When query Employee I need Company Information only, no need of Country.
2. But when I query Company I need Country.

How to avoid this inner queries when given EAGER.

*We tried LAZY, but we need to initialize the join queries which hits the Database multiple time.*

Is there anyway/configuration in Hibernate to avoid this?

Comment: Please show your queries.

Comment: i edited the question and added the queries.

Comment: One approach is to set all the associations to LAZY and then whenever you need to fetch them eargerly you adjust the query accordingly.